# CRM 2011 - Set field's 'requiredlevel' to REQUIRED based on another field's value

Tags: javascript, crm

I am working on the Opportunity form in CRM 2011.

I have 2 fields I am working with: azdb_payment1type & new_payment1cclast4orcheckgc

azdb_payment1type has option set values:

- Visa = 807,370,000
- Mastercard = 807,370,001
- American Express = 807,370,002
- Discover = 807,370,003
- Check = 807,370,004
- Cash = 807,370,005
- Credit Rollover = 807,370,006

IF the value of this field (azdb_payment1type) is 807,370,004 or less, I'd like to REQUIRE that the new_paymentcclast4orcheckgc field is filled out.

I created a function for the azdb_payment1type field called "requireCClast_onchange", then added the below code to the form's main library:

```
function requireCClast_onchange() {
  var payment1type = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('azdb_payment1type').getValue();
  alert(payment1type);
  if (payment1type <= '807,370,004') {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_payment1cclast4orcheckgc").setRequiredLevel("required");
  }
}
```

With the code inserted as onchange, nothing happens when I select a CC, then tab off the field.  If I change the function to onsave, then edit the library with the changes, it DOES return the alert I set up in the code, but it doesn't change the Requirement Level from "Business Recommended" to "Required".

Is this even possible with Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a look at this line. `payment1type <= '807,370,004'`

You are comparing a number to a string, I'm not sure have JavaScript will resolve that but I can't imagine its the way you would want.

I believe you should be doing, `payment1type <= 807370004`